# Docker image doesn't download every files properly

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, wget

I'm creating my docker image based on CentOS. I want to have it install SonarScanner, a build-wrapper and the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain in order to analyze C files. I wrote a Dockerfile in order to run those tasks.

After installing the required tools, I use the curl command to download the different archives. I don't encounter any problems downloading and extracting Sonar scanner and the Build Wrapper, but when I try to download the GNU ARM toolchain, my file system can't find it and therefore can't extract the archive. I find it weird since I'm using the exact same command as I did for the first two. I also tried using wget, with the same results. Here is my Dockerfile :

```
# Base image centos 7 for building
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y make wget unzip tar

#Downloading and extracting Sonar-Scanner

RUN export SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION=4.4.0.2170 \
    && export SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=$HOME/.sonar/sonar-scanner-$SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION-linux \
    && curl --create-dirs -sSLo $HOME/.sonar/sonar-scanner.zip https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-$SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION-linux.zip \
    && unzip -o $HOME/.sonar/sonar-scanner.zip -d $HOME/.sonar/ \
    && export PATH=$SONAR_SCANNER_HOME/bin:$PATH \
    && export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-server" 

#Downloading and extracting build-wrapper-x86

RUN curl --create-dirs -sSLo $HOME/.sonar/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip \
    && unzip -o $HOME/.sonar/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip -d $HOME/.sonar/ \
    && export PATH=$HOME/.sonar/build-wrapper-linux-x86:$PATH

RUN ls -la $HOME/.sonar/

#Downloading and installing ARM GCC embedded toolchain

RUN curl --create-dirs -sSLo $HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain.tar.bz2 https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/9-2020q2/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2?revision=05382cca-1721-44e1-ae19-1e7c3dc96118&la=en&hash=D7C9D18FCA2DD9F894FD9F3C3DC9228498FA281A \
&& tar xjf $HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain.tar.bz2 \
&& export ARM_GCC_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain \
&& export PATH=$ARM_GCC_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH

RUN ls -la $HOME/tools
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to create the image :

```
tar (child): /root/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I also tried to launch the command without the extracting part with a simple "ls -la $HOME/tools" to see if the dir was created, and the directory couldn't be found either.

Does anyone have an idea where this could come from and how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last URL contains special chars which are interpreted by the shell. The downloaded URL is bogus, and you don't notice because curl is set to run silently. The resulting file is corrupt. Solution : quote (or escape) your URL.

bzip2 is also missing in your image : you want to add it to your `yum install` command.

With these changes, your Dockerfile builds successfully:

```
--- Dockerfile.initial  2020-07-27 16:28:25.907617868 +0200
+++ Dockerfile  2020-07-27 16:29:14.347777643 +0200
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 # Base image centos 7 for building
 FROM centos:7

-RUN yum install -y make wget unzip tar
+RUN yum install -y make wget unzip tar bzip2

 #Downloading and extracting Sonar-Scanner

@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@

 #Downloading and installing ARM GCC embedded toolchain

-RUN curl --create-dirs -sSLo $HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain.tar.bz2 https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/9-2020q2/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2?revision=05382cca-1721-44e1-ae19-1e7c3dc96118&la=en&hash=D7C9D18FCA2DD9F894FD9F3C3DC9228498FA281A \
+RUN curl --create-dirs -sSLo $HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain.tar.bz2 'https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/9-2020q2/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2?revision=05382cca-1721-44e1-ae19-1e7c3dc96118&la=en&hash=D7C9D18FCA2DD9F894FD9F3C3DC9228498FA281A' \
 && tar xjf $HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain.tar.bz2 \
 && export ARM_GCC_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/tools/arm-gcc-embedded-toolchain \
 && export PATH=$ARM_GCC_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it !